# Dynamic content based on href route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm rendering a component on my nextjs app with some hard coded info (it's a [slug].tsx, the routing is working fine), but its content needs to be dynamic based on the href from the Link component. how could i make those props (code 2) obey the exact link the user clicked on?

```
      <Link href="collection/1" className="row-start-1 row-end-3">
        <Image
          src={serie[0].image}
          width={1000}
          height={1000}
          alt="pic1"
          style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        />
      </Link>
      <Link href="collection/2" className="row-start-1 row-end-2">
        <Image src={serie[1].image} width={1000} height={1000} alt="pic2" />
      </Link>
```

here's the component:

```
import { serie } from "../../data/serie";
import Collection from "../../src/Collection";

const CollectionPage = () => {
  return <Collection description={serie[0].description} img={serie[0].image} />;
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your `serie` collection's structure but I assume you have `id` for each array of object.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { serie } from "../../data/serie";
import Collection from "../../src/Collection";

const CollectionPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  // because your dynamic page is [slug].tsx
  // we get `slug` from the URL querystring
  // /collection/1 <- 1 is your slug
  const collectionId = router.query.slug;

  // find the serie according to the collectionId
  const currentCollection = serie.find((s) => s.id === collectionId);

  return currentCollection ? (
    <Collection
      description={currentCollection.description}
      img={currentCollection.image}
    />
  ) : (
    <div>There is no serie with {collectionId}</div>
  );
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

For further information: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Hope it helps.

Comment: wow that does it, thank you Abdullah!